# Failed to update a datetime table value in Mysql in the '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s' format

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlyog, mysqladministrator

I tried to update all table rows values using this sql function :

```
UPDATE night
SET started_at = DATE(
    STR_TO_DATE('13.05.2012 15:31:00','%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s')
)
```

but the result was **`2012-05-13 00:00:00`**.

I'm using the SQLyog community edition v8.12 and I have the database hosted using the MySQL administrator v1.2.17 and I don't know if the sql syntax used on those software's has a specific version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling [**`DATE()`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function:

> `DATE(expr)`
>
> Extracts the date part of the date or datetime expression `expr`.

Thus the time part of your expression is dropped. Just use:

```
UPDATE night
SET started_at = STR_TO_DATE('13.05.2012 15:31:00','%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s')
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me :

```
UPDATE `night` SET started_at = (SELECT STR_TO_DATE('13.05.2012 15:31:00','%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s'));
```